# Upsampling int series within groups for a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

My question is about how to upsample an int series for each of multiple 'grouping' within my dataframe. (In my case, for each 'Team' and 'LeadWeek' grouping).

I see built in functions and lots of examples for upsampling a timeseries, but not for upsampling integers. For various reasons I won't get into right now, I want to do this with integers instead of timeseries.

In my case I have 'Teams' and 'LeadWeeks' and I want to upsample 'Conversion Weeks' to be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] for each 'Team' and 'LeadWeek' combination.

I think there's a way to do this with `multi-index`/`groupby` + `resample()`, but I'm not smart enough to figure it out after a few hours tinkering. Asking for help from the wise ones here...

So here is the example data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['Team A', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 1), 0, 2]
,['Team A', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 1), 2, 1]
,['Team A', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 1), 4, 1]
,['Team A', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 8), 3, 2]
,['Team B', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 1), 0, 1]
,['Team B', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 1), 2, 3]
,['Team B', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 8), 1, 3]
,['Team B', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 8), 3, 2]
]
, columns=['Team', 'LeadWeek', 'ConversionWeek', 'Conversions']
)
```

My desired output is below, with each Team/LeadWeek grouping having 5 'ConversionWeek' rows, numbered 0 to 4:

```
       Team     LeadWeek     ConversionWeek     Conversions
0      Team A     2017-12-01     0     2.0
1      Team A     2017-12-01     1     0.0
2      Team A     2017-12-01     2     1.0
3      Team A     2017-12-01     3     0.0
4      Team A     2017-12-01     4     1.0
5      Team A     2017-12-08     0     0.0
6      Team A     2017-12-08     1     0.0
7      Team A     2017-12-08     2     0.0
8      Team A     2017-12-08     3     2.0
9      Team A     2017-12-08     4     0.0
10     Team B     2017-12-01     0     1.0
11     Team B     2017-12-01     1     0.0
12     Team B     2017-12-01     2     3.0
13     Team B     2017-12-01     3     0.0
14     Team B     2017-12-01     4     0.0
15     Team B     2017-12-08     0     0.0
16     Team B     2017-12-08     1     3.0
17     Team B     2017-12-08     2     0.0
18     Team B     2017-12-08     3     2.0
19     Team B     2017-12-08     4     0.0
```

I do have a solution for this, but it is not very pythonic. It is the same as how I would solve it in SQL, which is to create a 'scaffold' using a Cartesian product of all of the distinct elements, and then join my actual Conversions to it. In Python this method uses `itertools.product()`

My solution is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

df = pd.DataFrame([
['Team A', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 1), 0, 2]
,['Team A', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 1), 2, 1]
,['Team A', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 1), 4, 1]
,['Team A', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 8), 3, 2]
,['Team B', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 1), 0, 1]
,['Team B', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 1), 2, 3]
,['Team B', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 8), 1, 3]
,['Team B', pd.datetime(2017, 12, 8), 3, 2]
]
, columns=['Team', 'LeadWeek', 'ConversionWeek', 'Conversions']
)

ConversionWeek = np.linspace(0, 4, 5, dtype=int)

Team = df['Team'].unique()

LeadWeek = df['LeadWeek'].unique()

scaffold_raw = []

for i in it.product(Team, LeadWeek, ConversionWeek):
    scaffold_raw.append(i)

scaffold = pd.DataFrame(scaffold_raw, columns=['Team', 'LeadWeek', 'ConversionWeek'])

new_frame = scaffold.merge(df, how='left')

new_frame = new_frame.sort_values(by=['Team', 'LeadWeek', 'ConversionWeek']).reset_index(drop=True)

new_frame['Conversions'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Appreciate any help on a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reindex` by passing a `pd.MultiIndex` -

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
      [df.Team.unique(), df.LeadWeek.unique(), np.arange(5)]
)   

v = df.set_index(['Team', 'LeadWeek', 'ConversionWeek'])\
      .reindex(idx)\
      .fillna(0)\
      .reset_index()

v.columns = df.columns    
v

      Team   LeadWeek  ConversionWeek  Conversions
0   Team A 2017-12-01               0          2.0
1   Team A 2017-12-01               1          0.0
2   Team A 2017-12-01               2          1.0
3   Team A 2017-12-01               3          0.0
4   Team A 2017-12-01               4          1.0
5   Team A 2017-12-08               0          0.0
6   Team A 2017-12-08               1          0.0
7   Team A 2017-12-08               2          0.0
8   Team A 2017-12-08               3          2.0
9   Team A 2017-12-08               4          0.0
10  Team B 2017-12-01               0          1.0
11  Team B 2017-12-01               1          0.0
12  Team B 2017-12-01               2          3.0
13  Team B 2017-12-01               3          0.0
14  Team B 2017-12-01               4          0.0
15  Team B 2017-12-08               0          0.0
16  Team B 2017-12-08               1          3.0
17  Team B 2017-12-08               2          0.0
18  Team B 2017-12-08               3          2.0
19  Team B 2017-12-08               4          0.0
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!